# How to iterate over a non-empty string?

Tags: java, string, list

I need to iterate over some String if it's not empty. I mean this:

```
for (String email : partnerEmails.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<String>()
                    : partnerEmails.split("\\s*,\\s*")) {
    selectedEmails.add(email);
}
```

The thing that I'm worried about is that I'm creating a new empty `list` which takes some resources and memory, and need to be garbage collected soon. How can I avoid that?

Comment: why iterate over an empty arraylist that you have just constructed?

Comment: @vefthym Becaus if I didn't I would get a list with an empty string which was not what I wanted.

Comment: why don't you split your partnerEmails string into an array of Strings?

Answer (score 1):

You could enter the loop only `if ((null != partnerEmails) && !partnerEmails.isEmpty())`.
If you want to keep your loop, you could define a `private static ArrayList<String> EMPTY_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();` and iterate over this list instead.

Answer (score 1):

Validate empty before iterating:

```
if (!partnerEmails.isEmpty())
    for (String email : partnerEmails.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
        selectedEmails.add(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) [Collections.emptyList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList) solves the problem of creating a new object every time (not that you should worry about such micro-optimizations).

2) You don't need the iterator. Instead, use the code below:

```
List<String> emails = partnerEmails.isEmpty()
                    ? Collections.emptyList()
                    : Arrays.asList(partnerEmails.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
selectedEmails.addAll(emails);
```